# Create react HOC with props children

Tags: reactjs

I understand the react higher order component example from the official docs but I want to use it slightly differently if possible, with props.children - ie

```html
<PageHoc> // Higher order component 
     <Route exact path="/" component={Invite}  /> // I want to auto inject props here
</PageHoc>
```

In my page HOC I can auto render out the child component but how can I attach some new props here?

```html
import React from 'react';

  class PageHoc extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children
    }
  }
    
export default PageHoc;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `PageHoc` component technically is just a parent component, not a HOC as it isn't wrapping and returning a *new* component. But you can still inject props into children component via react's `Children` helper and `cloneElement`.

```
import React, { Children, Component, createElement } from 'react';

class PageParent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return Children.map(
      this.props.children, 
      child => cloneElement(child, { injectedProp: injectedPropValue })
    );
  }
}

export default PageParent;
```

As HOC

```
const withInjectedProps = WrappedComponent => {
  const injectedProps = {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2,
    <...etc...>
  };
  return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...injectedProps} />
}

export default withInjectedProps;

const InjectedRoute = withInjectedProps(Route);

<InjectedRoute exact path="/" component={Invite} /> // has props injected
<InjectedRoute exact path="/a" component={OtherComponent} /> // has props injected too!
```

Kind of depends how you need to inject the props, if you have have just a single component, many, etc..

I forgot to mention that react HOCs by convention are named starting with "with", but this isn't the rule, i.e. react-redux's `connect`.

[react HOC docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: Thanks, is there a name for this pattern(first one)? I dont want to call it HOC anymore if its something different.

Comment: I don't know if it has a name, the react docs do not seem to call it anything specific.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to clone the children and override the props like this,

```
  import React from 'react';

  class PageHoc extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    doSomething = () => {
    //your logic
    }
    render() {
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { doSomething: this.doSomething })
    );

    return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
    }
  }

  export default PageHoc;
```