# Issues receiving parameters in High Order Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, react-hoc

I want to adjust a demo provided by some tutorial about React Design Patterns, subject: **Higher Order Component**.

In the  code **the argument '2' for an userId is hardcoded** inside of the component and can be **found in the last line of the component `UserInfoForm`**.

My question: How can I use a parameter here instead, that I can send to the withEditableUser HOC when calling it like this?

```
withEditableUser(UserInfoForm, 4);
```

Any help, tips, additional sources to learn this would be highly appreciated.

**Here's the HOC with the hardcoded argument:**

```
import {withEditableUser} from './withEditableUser';

export const UserInfoForm  = withEditableUser(({ user, onChangeUser, onSaveUser, onResetUser }) => {
    const { name, email, username } = user || {};

    console.log(user)

    return user ? (
        <>
        <label>
            Name:
            <input value={name} onChange={e => onChangeUser({ name: e.target.value })} />
        </label>
        <label>
            Email:
            <input value={email} onChange={e => onChangeUser({ email: e.target.value })} />
        </label>
        <label>
            Username:
            <input value={username} onChange={e => onChangeUser({ username: e.target.value })} />
        </label>
        <button onClick={onResetUser}>Reset</button>
        <button onClick={onSaveUser}>Save Changes</button>
        </>
    ) : <p>Loading...</p>;
}
, '2');
```

Comment: I know this is a distracting answer, but really you should try to avoid the HOC pattern nowadays. Its not completely useless as you will see it in existing older code, and there are still some useful cases also. However, mostly its replaced by custom hooks.

Comment: The answer though would require you to post the definition of `withEditableUser`

Answer (score 0):

As you implement a HOC, which will be a shareable component so,

It's better to send that **variable as prop** to component,

The way how it works is, first of all your props will be received by HOC, than from HOC you have to forward these props to child component If needed in child.

As an example you can have a look at

[Passing Props from HOC to child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885002/create-react-hoc-with-props-children)

[Passing Props through HOC from route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694176/pass-props-through-a-higher-order-component-from-a-route)